# Howto check open ports of a specific tomcat java instance

Tags: bash, tomcat, java, shell, activemq

For the moment I've managed to do it with:

```
root@server:~# for i in $(netstat -lp | grep java | awk '{print $7}' | awk -F '/' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq); do ap=$(ps p $i | grep -v PID | grep activemq | awk '{print $1}'); done; netstat -lp | grep $ap
tcp        0      0 localhost:32000         *:*                     LISTEN      23059/java      
tcp6       0      0 HPM.DMZ:61616           [::]:*                  LISTEN      23059/java      
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8161               [::]:*                  LISTEN      23059/java      
tcp6       0      0 [::]:36168              [::]:*                  LISTEN      23059/java
```

It checks all process IDs belonging to open network ports, checks whether or not it is a tomcat instance "activemq".

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This one will be a bit more terse; it checks which are the pids of processes named "`.*activemq.*`" and after that checks their opened ports:

```
netstat -lp | grep  $(ps aux | awk '/[a]ctivemq/ {print $2}')
```

You can add a uniq filter if you need to:

```
netstat -lp | grep  $(ps aux | awk '/[a]ctivemq/ {print $2}' | sort -u)
```

EDITED BASED ON JOE's COMMENTS:

> Joe Nazz wrote:
>
> It doesn't work. The result of """$(ps aux | awk '/[a]ctivemq/ {print $2}' | sort -u)""" are multiple lines, that grep cannot recognize. It comes "No such file or dir..." –

You are right, If there are several processes we need to work a bit more in our grep's regexp expression.

So in order to keep my **run-netstat-just-once** command, the expression should be something similar to:

```
~# netstat -lp | grep $(ps aux | awk '/[a]pache/ {a=a"\|"$2} END { sub(/^../,"",a); print "("a")"}')
```

The command creates a regexp to match each pid of apache (I'm using apache2 as a multi instance process to match your needs). As you'll see in the following expression, the regexp created tries to match every single pid of apache:

```
~# ps aux | awk '/[a]pache/ {a=a"\|"$2} END { sub(/^../,"",a); print "("a")"}'
(7335\|7336\|7337\|7338\|7339\|8733\|8744\|13418\|13421\|23126)
```

> – Joe Nazz wrote:
>
> [...] But what does the single 'a' in the brackets mean? –

About your question related of why I used the [a] in the regexp, it is a very old trick to avoid matching the process created by the regexp it self. The following example is self explanatory:

```
~# ps aux | grep foo
root     10932  0.0  0.0   9608   868 pts/0    S+   11:42   0:00 grep foo
~# ps aux | grep "[f]oo"
~#
```

PS: if you feel this answer was helpful please don't leave unvoted

Comment: Nice, thx! But what does the single 'a' in the brackets mean?

Comment: It doesn't work. The result of """$(ps aux | awk '/[a]ctivemq/ {print $2}' | sort -u)""" are multiple lines, that grep cannot recognize. It comes "No such file or dir..."

Comment: See my post edition. Answers both of your comments

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(ps aux | awk '/activemq/ {print $2}' | sort -gu); do netstat -lp | grep $i; done

tcp        0      0 localhost:32000         *:*                     LISTEN      23059/java      
tcp6       0      0 HPM.DMZ:61616           [::]:*                  LISTEN      23059/java      
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8161               [::]:*                  LISTEN      23059/java      
tcp6       0      0 [::]:36168              [::]:*                  LISTEN      23059/java
```

was shorter but it calls *netstat* multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

This retrieves "activemq" pids, tests that one was returned, runs netstat once.

```
pids=`ps -eo 'pid,args' | awk '/activemq/ && !/awk/ {print $1}'`
test -n "${pids}" && netstat -lp | egrep -w "(`echo ${pids} | tr ' ' '|'`)"
```